# Skew is causing page height to stretch really tall

Tags: css

Having an issue with skew here. Here is my markup:

```
    <div class="skew skew_outer">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="skew skew_1">
            <div class="skew skew_2">
                <div class="skew skew_3">
                    <div class="headerwrap">
                        <div class="site-branding">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'header-logo' ); ?>
                        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

                        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'full-width-skeleton-theme' ); ?></button>
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
                        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
                    </div> <!-- End Header Wrapper --> 
                </div> <!-- End Skew Three --> 
            </div> <!-- End Skew Two -->
        </div> <!-- End Skew One -->

    </header><!-- #masthead -->
</div> <!-- End Outer Skew -->
```

And here is my styling (SCSS):

```
.site-header{
background: #c2c2c2;
transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
height: 301px;
.skew_3{
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    transform: skew(0deg, 1deg);

}
.skew_2{
    background:$med_blue;
    transform: skew(0deg, 1deg);
    height: 240px;
}
.skew_1{
    background:$light_blue;
    transform: skew(0deg, -2deg);
    height: 280px;
}

.headerwrap{
    background: transparent;
    transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
    padding: .5rem 0 0;
    @include main-wrapper;

    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason this code is causing the height of the page to expand way too high. I've tried applying a few overflow:hidden's on the header and skew_n classes, however that obviously just cuts the skewed borders off and makes the elements rectangular again.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out folks. If you're using the Underscores starter theme (or any theme where your menu works like what I'm about to say), and you have a negative skew on the page header (rare case, right?), you need to change the way your menu works.

By default, it sends the submenu  way off to the left of the page with absolute positioning, which due to the skew on the header, is causing it to be really far down and to the left, thus making the page higher (since it's so far down on the page now.)